# Debug View Hierarchy limitations?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I've been making good use of the new Debug View Hierarchy (DVH) capability in Xcode 6.1.

But, today, I added a few more views and Auto-layout constraints to my app and now the DVH shows me nothing.

I run my app, get the view up I want to look at, go to the DVH and there's nothing there.  Following that, I can resume code execution with no problems.   So far as I can see, my code seems to be working fine.

Has anyone else run into this situation?  Am I up against some limit here?  Perhaps the DVH can only show so much complexity?  Any known ways around this?

Comment: Going to shut this question down.  I forgot the simplest rule of what to do when something doesn't work.  Stop and Reboot.  This morning, all is well again.  Yours truly - sheepish in New Zealand.